# Stacking arrays in numpy using vstack

Tags: python, numpy

`array1.shape` gives (180, )
`array2.shape` gives (180, 1)

What's the difference between these two?
And because of this difference I'm unable to stack them using

```
np.vstack((array2, array1))
```

What changes should I make to array1 shape so that I can stack them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define some arrays:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((4, 1))
>>> y = np.zeros((4))
```

As is, these arrays fail to stack:

```
>>> np.vstack((x, y))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 230, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

However, with a simple change, they will stack:

```
>>> np.vstack((x, y[:, None]))
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> np.vstack((x[:, 0], y))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [81]: x1=np.ones((10,)); x2=np.ones((10,1))
```

One array is 1d, the other 2d.  `vertical` stack requires 2 dimensions, vertical and horizontal.  So `np.vstack` passes each input through `np.atleast_2d`:

```
In [82]: np.atleast_2d(x1).shape
Out[82]: (1, 10)
```

But now we have a (1,10) array and a (10,1) - they can't be joined in either axis.

But if we reshape `x1` so it is `(10,1)`, then we can join it with `x2` in either direction:

```
In [83]: np.concatenate((x1[:,None],x2), axis=0).shape
Out[83]: (20, 1)
In [84]: np.concatenate((x1[:,None],x2), axis=1).shape
Out[84]: (10, 2)
```

Print out the two arrays:

```
In [86]: x1
Out[86]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
In [87]: x2
Out[87]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

How can you concatenate those two shapes without some sort of adjustment?